# itunes: can't get playlist to play more than one song w/o having to manually hit "play"?

Tags: itunes, playlists

Something is screwy with my itunes setup... I can play multiple songs after each other from the Music Library, but if I want to play several songs in a row from a playlist, it doesn't seem to work. It plays one and then stops. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARGH -- never mind, I figured it out -- you have to have songs checked; it only plays the checked songs automatically, and skips the unchecked songs.

I wish iTunes handled some of these things a little more intuitively or at least gave you feedback if you're not doing things the way it likes.

Comment: You shouldn't have to select songs in a playlist to get them to play.

Comment: Yeah there's something else going on here because that's not normal behavior.

Comment: sorry, meant checked, not selected.

Comment: Smarty pants I thought I was when I wanted to use the option "Only sync checked tunes to ipod" as a means to make my ipod playlist on the fly using checkmarks in iTunes without playlists, until I found out that it affected playback behavior in iTunes. Back then sent feedback to the Void, erm I mean to Apple, to tell them this feature had overlapping functionality and should be customizable.

Comment: As a workaround for that, try the manually manage songs option, then click and drag the ones you want to the iPod.

Comment: I agree this seems like a change,  but here's another link that supports it...  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5106163?tstart=0